Circularity in the definition of natural numbers with homotopy type theory
I am reading HoTT's book, I am interested in this theory because it is said that it works as a foundation of mathematics, so I want to see how this foundation works. I am interested in the definition of a formal system of homotopy-type theory. HoTT's book has an appendix called "A formal type theory" where this is done, but the way how it is done is confusing for me because of the next reasons.
I quote:
 We postulate a hierarchy of universes denoted by primitive constants
$$
\mathcal{U}_0,\ \mathcal{U}_1,\ \mathcal{U}_2,\ ... 
$$
Here is where my confusion begins. Until this point natural numbers have not been defined, so what does it mean that $0$ in $\mathcal{U}_0$, that $1$ in $\mathcal{U}_1$? That's essentially my doubt. One could think that it is just a sign, but I don't think so, because what the postulate means is that there is an infinite hierarchy of universes.
I quote again:
The type of natural numbers is obtained by introducing primitive constants $0,\mathbb{N}$ and $succ$ with the following rules
$\mathbb{N}:\mathcal{U}_0$.
$0:\mathbb{N}$.
$succ : \mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$
Futhermore, we can define functions by primitive recursion. If we have $C:\mathbb{N}\to\mathcal{U}_K$ we can introduce a...

Here, what is the difference between $0$ in $\mathcal{U}_0$ and in $0:\mathbb{N}$? they can't be both the zero natural number, because then we have that the definition of zero is circular. What does it mean $k$ in $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathcal{U}_k$? It can't be a natural numbers because it is part of the definition, so what is it?
Does this mean that the definition of natural numbers in homotopy type theory is circular?
I hope someone can help to understand this. Thanks.

The indices for the universes are part of the meta-theory of HoTT, and not of the theory itself.
The exact definition of the indices is not really important: if you are able to define an unlimited, ordered list of symbols, then you can use it to index the universes of the theory. There will be no recursion, quantification on them, they are just used as mere symbols. The HoTT book just supposes that you are able to define and order such a list of mere symbols.
If you are not satisfied with it, it is possible to give a formal definition of the indices themselves. This is proposed for instance here. But at the end of the day, understanding formal rules always require some pre-existing knowledge, it's not possible to start from nothing. What is important is not that everything is defined from scratch, but that the pre-requisites can be reduced to basic symbol manipulations.

When you say "if you are able to define an unlimited, ordered list of symbols" I think that any such ordered list is isomorphic to natural numbers, then, I think by Univalence (informal univalence), we are talking about natural numbers. Therefore I take the approach given in your link, I personally think that the best solution is to define Peano Arithmetic first.

@RataMágica I think that the 'best solution' depends on the point of view. From my point of view 'natural numbers' without the possibility to use them to enumerate anything else are just a dead skeleton of natural numbers. Functions matter as much as objects, if not more.
